# adding elements one by one to a new list in prolog recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog

given `add(X,InputList,OutputList)`
where `Outputlist` is a sequence of X elements from `InputList`. we read `InputList` count the number of elements and add elements to `Outputlist` till we reach X elements.

i have tried to use the member and then tried to append the elements but i cant seem to figure out how to return the new list also made size to get the size of the input list

```
size([],0).
size([H|T],N) :- size(T,N1), N is N1+1.
```

```
append2([], List2, List2).
append2([H|T], List2, [H|Result]) :- append2(T, List2, Result)
```

actual results should look like this

```
add(4, [1,2,3], X)
(0, [a,b,c,d], X).
```

and these fail

```
add(0,[q],[q]).
```

```
add(3,[a,b,z,c],[a,b,c]).
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pleased that you're attempting to use library predicates to accomplish this task. You could, for instance, do something like this:

```
add(N, List, Prefix) :-
    length(Prefix, N),
    append(Prefix, _, List).
```

This says, in effect, "Prefix is a list of length N, which can be appended to something or other to produce the input List." There is, of course, no reason for you to bother implementing your own versions of `length/2` and `append/3` since they are ISO.

If you wanted to do it manually, you could do it by a case analysis and using `succ/2`, which would look something like this:

```
add(0, _, []).
add(N, [X|Xs], [X|Result]) :-
   succ(N0, N),
   add(N0, Xs, Result).
```

In general, this predicate is called `take/3` because it's as though OutputList is just the result of taking N elements from InputList.